# Jenkins LDAP - root DN & Display Name LDAP attribute

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap, jenkins-plugins, displayname-attribute

This question is about Jenkins LDAP `root DN` & `Display Name LDAP attribute`

**Environment:-**

```
Jenkins Version - 2.235.5(LTS)
LDAP Plugin - 1.24
```

I am trying to configure LDAP(AD) Authentication in our Jenkins, Below is the configuration settings.

```
root DN - DC=Company,DC=domain,DC=com
User search base: OU=Users,OU=Division,OU=Team,DC=Company,DC=domain,DC=com
User search filter: sAMAccountName={0}
Group search base: OU=Users,OU=Division,OU=Team,DC=Company,DC=domain,DC=com
Group search filter: (&(objectclass=group)(cn={0}))
Group membership
   Group membership filter - (&(objectCategory=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0}))
Manager DN: CN=jenkins,OU=Users,OU=Division,OU=Team,DC=Company,DC=domain,DC=com
Manager Password: password
Display Name LDAP attribute: displayname
Email Address LDAP attribute: mail
```

But while testing the LDAP connection it fails below error.

```
Login
Authentication: failed for user "jenkins-user"
Lookup
User lookup: failed for user "jenkins-user"
LdapCallback;[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'DC=domain,DC=com'
]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'DC=domain,DC=com'
]; remaining name 'OU=Users,OU=Division,OU=Team,DC=Company,DC=domain,DC=com'
LDAP Group lookup: could not verify.
Please try with a user that is a member of at least one LDAP group.
Lockout
The user "jenkins-user" will be unable to login with the supplied password.
If this is your own account this would mean you would be locked out!
Are you sure you want to save this configuration?
```

Suppose if i keep the `root DN` as empty and `enabled the tick mark` - `Allow blank rootDN`. my test connection is getting successful.

But i would like to know that currently i am running `root DN` as empty and `enabled - Allow blank rootDN` in plugin section. Is this is fine for production environment?

Also for the logged in users, The display name shown as below which is too lengthy.

```
First-Name/Sur-Name/Team-Name/Location/Title/Company-Name
```

i would like to display only `First-Name + Sur-Name`. For this i tried to change `Display Name LDAP attribute:` with `name, givenName, cn & sn` but none of them were worked. So is it possible to display only First name + Sur-name in Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it. Each time when we `change/update` the `Display Name LDAP attribute` value in LDAP configuration section, We need to `delete` the user from people category and need to login. Post that it displays the configured settings.